# how to ask if an array is a string?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, hash, type-conversion

I'm trying to write a function to change arrays to hash values, I've done it so that I can change a numerical array into their hash values but I can't seem to figure out how to change string arrays into their hash values.

I'm having trouble doing it with string arrays. for example if array= [aced]

this is my code so far.

```
 function [h]=Hash31(array1)
 n=length(array1);
 i=1;
 h=0;
 if array1
 for i=1:1:n
 h=array1(i)+31*h;
 end
 end
```

and it turns a numerical array into their hash value.
I was wondering if I had to do some kind of conversion or logical to make it work
and if I did to that how would I fit it into the existing function.
would it have to be a logical, because I've tried using an if function but I don't know how to write in code 'if the array is string, then...' in a way that Matlab understands.

Comment: Look for `isstring` to determine if something is a string array. You can convert each element of the string array (each string) into a char array using `char`; you can iterate over the letters of the char array. You might also have to handle cell arrays, maybe?

Comment: thanks for the help and the criticism from before. I'm kinda new at this and haven't been practicing as much as I should with my other classes going on, ill try and do better.